# How do clocks, at rest wrt to us, in a saddle-shaped 3D space tick relative to one another?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, time, curvature, space

Clocks placed in a 3D flat space all tick at the same rate, if we look at them when we are at rest wrt to them.

On a positively curved space around a mass, the clocks show different paces if we are at rest wrt to them. For example, if we place clocks at various heights above the surface of the Earth, we see the clocks tick faster higher above it.

Now imagine we are in a 3D saddle-shaped space, which is negatively curved, and we place clocks on various spots around us. The clocks are at rest wrt us.

What can we expect? How will the clocks tick relative to one another?

I make no assumptions about the source of the negative curvature. Maybe negative mass or negative energy.

Comment: I think you need to add some details or clarifications here. Clocks on a positively curved space do not necessarily tick at different rates -- in fact the tick rates has nothing to do with the shape of the Earth, but rather of the gravitational potential where the clocks are located.

Comment: @EricSmith Don't clocks at fixed positions on the manifold around the Earth tick at different rates? On a spherical 2D shape this isnt the case though.

Comment: @EricSmith I didn't involve the shape of the Earth. But the space around Earth.

Comment: Only clocks at different gravitational potentials (which for Earth means different heights, basically). So for example all clocks at sea level tick at the same rate, regardless of where on the surface they are (to a first approximation. in the real world things are slightly more complicated than in an ideal world)..

Comment: It's the warping of spacetime (mostly time) that affects relative clock speeds, not just the warping of space. In general you'd need to write down the metric of your spacetime and use that to figure out how clocks behave. I'm not sure if a "saddle shaped spacetime" is something that can actually be achieved without negative energy.

Comment: @EricSmith Yes. Thats all clear. But what if instead if the 3D positively curved spacepart, it was a negatively curved one. How would the clocks tick at different locations?

Comment: @EricSmith Exactly. Negative energy. What if the spacepart was a saddle shape. How would the clocks tick relative to one another?

Comment: @EricSmith What if this negative curvature was caused by virtual particles. What is the shape of an empty quantum vacuum? Virtual particles oscillate in time.

Comment: There's no coherent theory of quantum gravity yet, so some things we can't answer. But the general rule in relativity is that clocks go slower in the direction that they fall in, so if you somehow constructed a situation where clocks fell "up" then the higher clocks would go slower .

Comment: @EricSmith is there a solution in GR for a shape of spacetime in which masses move away from each other? Isn't a saddle shaped space such a one?

Comment: @EricSmith “*Only clocks at different gravitational potentials [tick at different rates]*” - This is conceptually misleading. You are confusing GR with the Newtonian Gravity. The cause of gravity in GR is the gradient of the time dilation. So the time dilation is the primary factor that does not depend on any separately defined “gravitational potential”. If you want to introduce “gravitational potential” in GR, it would be a function of and therefore depend on the time dilation. Not the other way around.

Comment: @Felicia “*the curvature of space has nothing to do with gravity (the 'curvature of time’)*” - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellis_wormhole - The rate of clocks does not depend on the shape of space. As mentioned in the comments, things fall to where time moves slower. So if you find a material that repels objects, then time near this material would move faster. A good question, except you should be asking about the shape of spacetime, not of space +1

Comment: @safesphere : the cause of both gravity and time dilation in GR is the curvature of spacetime. The "gradient of time dilation" can explain only Newtonian gravitational effects, but post-Newtonian ones like the precession of Mercury and deflection of light require taking into account the curvature of space, too. Under most conditions the gravitational time dilation at a point in a gravitational field is the same as the SR time dilation due to escape velocity, which is why I described it as related to "gravitational potential", but you're right that it's really due to spacetime curvature.

Comment: @EricSmith Indeed, but just to clarify, the curvature of spacetime consists of the curvature of space (length contraction) and curvature of time (time dilation). So the time dilation is not *caused* by the curvature of spacetime, but *is* a part of it. The gradient of the time dilation defines the gravitational acceleration *locally*, but without the Newtonian limitation. There is no gravitational acceleration in a curved space without a time dilation.